# How to fix "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" error in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python with very little experience in coding. I've started writing a Python program to multiply two matrices.
The following code gives me output for square matrices but gives me the following error when I enter, say for example, m=2, n=3, p=3, q=2:

```
"a[i][j] = (int(input()))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range"
```

Could anybody please help me out with this? Thank you!

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
m=int(input('Enter number of rows of matrix I:'))
n=int(input('Enter number of columns of matrix I:'))

p=int(input('Enter number of rows of matrix II:'))
q=int(input('Enter number of columns of matrix II:'))


if n!=p:
    print('\nThese matrices cannot be multiplied!')
else:
    a = [[[] for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
    b = [[[] for i in range(p)] for j in range(q)]
    c = [[[] for i in range(m)] for j in range(q)]

print('Enter elements of matrix I:')
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print('Element (', i, ',', j, '):', end="")
        a[i][j] = (int(input()))

print('Enter elements of matrix II:')
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        print('Element (', i, ',', j, '):', end="")
        b[i][j] = (int(input()))
sum = 0
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(q):
        for k in range(n):
            sum = sum + a[i][k] * b[k][j]
        c[i][j] = sum
        sum = 0
print('\nResultant matrix:')
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(q):
        print(c[i][j],"\t\t\t",end="")
    print()
```

**strong text**

Comment: You have your rows and columns mixed up. You have `m` columns and `n` rows.

Comment: You have your indexes in wrong order, it should be `a[j][i] = (int(input()))`, same for rest of your code.

Comment: The problem is in matrix initialization step with list comprehension. The original matrix itself is contained within a list, so it is a 3D list.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of trivial tracing statements helped find the problem: your dimension limits are switched.  Try this:

```
print('Enter elements of matrix I:')
print("TRACE", a)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m): 
        print('Element (', i, ',', j, '):', end="")
        a[i][j] = (int(input()))
    print("TRACE", a)
```

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix definition for `a`, `b`, and `c` are producing a 3D matrix instead of your desired 2D matrix with rows and columns.

## Option 1

Put a placeholder value of `0` in each cell of the matrix as such:

```
# notice n is the number of columns and m is the number of rows
a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)] # this will create n zeroes within m lists
b = [[0 for i in range(q)] for j in range(p)]
c = [[0 for i in range(q)] for j in range(m)]
```

resulting matrix shape for 2x3 a and 3x4

```
a = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
b = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
c = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

## Option 2

Put an empty list for each row of the matrix, and `append` columns to each row.

```
a = [[] for i in range(m)] # this will create m empty lists
b = [[] for i in range(p)]
c = [[] for i in range(m)]
```

Resulting matrix is a list containing row-number of empty lists.

```
a = [[], []]
b = [[], [], []]
c = [[], []]
```

Then you want to append instead of indexing for matrix[i][j] since columns don't yet exist.

```
# within the two for loops asking for matrix values and in constructing the resulting matrix...
a[i].append((int(input())))
b[i].append((int(input())))
c[i].append(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just Post the Complete Solution. you can read @Endyd Answer for the Explanation.

```
m=int(input('Enter number of rows of matrix I:'))
n=int(input('Enter number of columns of matrix I:'))

p=int(input('Enter number of rows of matrix II:'))
q=int(input('Enter number of columns of matrix II:'))


if n!=p:
    print('\nThese matrices cannot be multiplied!')
else:
    # notice n is the number of columns and m is the number of rows
    a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)] # this will create n zeroes within m lists
    #print(a)
    b = [[0 for i in range(q)] for j in range(p)]
    #print(b)
    c = [[0 for i in range(q)] for j in range(m)]
    #print(c)
print('Enter elements of matrix I:')
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        #print('Element (', i, ',', j, '):')
        a[i][j] = (int(input()))
        print(a)
print('Enter elements of matrix II:')
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        #print('Element (', i, ',', j, '):')
        b[i][j] = (int(input()))
        print(b)
sum = 0
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(q):
        for k in range(n):
            sum = sum + a[i][k] * b[k][j]
        c[i][j] = sum
        sum = 0
print('\nResultant matrix:')
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(q):
        print(c[i][j])
    print(c)
'''
```